# Convert coordinate to DMS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, degrees-minutes-seconds

I'm trying to convert coordinates to DMS, I try to use field calculator, but I still have no result.

I also try this script:

```
(CASE WHEN $x < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END) || 
floor (abs($x)) || '°' || 
floor(((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60) ||'\'' || 
substr(
  (tostring(
    (((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60) - floor(((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60)) * 60),
  1,
  5) || '" E'"
```

Any proposition?

Comment: What happened when you ran the script that you have presented?

Comment: I receive an empty field !!

Comment: When you use the || symbol to join strings, if any of the strings are NULL, the entire output is empty. Try using the `concat()` function instead of concatenating with || and see if that helps.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `to_dms` expression.

`to_dms($x, 'x', 3)`

If your geometry is not in EPSG:4326, reproject it on the fly, like this:

`to_dms(x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:2154','EPSG:4326')), 'x', 3)`

Source : http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.4-LTR/#map-expressions

Comment: using to_dms in Map Canvas give me an error, e.g. 

````to_dms(x_min(map_get( item_variables( 'Map 1'),'map_extent')),'x',3)````

but using ````x()```` is okay ...

Comment: Yes, the canvas does not have the variable 'Map 1'. There is already variables `@map_extent`, `$x`, `$y` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Open the attribute table and start editing, then open the field calculator; Create a new text field of length 16, named ‘lon_dms’, and enter the code below in the ‘Expression’ box; Calculate, then repeat for ‘lat_dms’ but change each $x to $y; Save

```
(CASE WHEN $x < 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'S' END) || floor (abs($x)) || '°' || floor(((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60) ||'\'' || substr( (tostring((((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60) - floor(((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60)) * 60),1,5) || '"'
```

[I got this code from www.underdiverwaterman.com, but the link/website is currently down]

Comment: I receive an empty field !!

Answer (score 0):

I substituted the `concat(string1,string2,string3)` concatenation method for the || character. When concatenating a complicated expression like this, `concat()` is better because it converts NULL values to empty strings. When using ||, if the expression has any mistakes that evaluate to NULL, the whole output is empty, which is very difficult to troubleshoot. I did a bit of additional cleaning up and fixed a few mistakes (see my notes below). It's not perfect yet, but it should give you a starting point for more troubleshooting.

```
concat(CASE WHEN $x < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END, 
floor(abs($x)),
 '°', 
floor(((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60),
'`',
substr( tostring((((abs($x)) - floor (abs($x))) * 60) - floor(((abs($x)) - floor(abs($x))) * 60)) * 60,  1,  5),
'`` E')
```

Notes:

The biggest issue was the `'\''` term. I assume the backslash is supposed to escape the single quotation mark, but it wasn't working that way. Instead it was printing a backslash as though the expression was `'\'` and then everything after the third single quotation mark was converted into a string.

I couldn't figure out a way to get the single quotation mark into the output, so I gave up and substituted the tick mark: `

If it's important that you have a single quotation mark in there, try playing around with the `char(code)` function. It should take a unicode code number and convert it into that symbol. I tried a few different unicode values that should convert to an apostrophe or single quote, and they gave me boxes or square corner brackets. Maybe QGIS uses a different version of unicode than my Google search results, or maybe the preview is just broken.

Another issue was the final term, `'" E'"`. I used the same workaround as for the minutes, and just substituted a double tick mark. If you want some single or double quotes in the final output, see my notes above.